# Docker in exited(1) state

Tags: docker

I am new to the Docker.

When I run this 1st command, I have no issue, I can browse the application

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v "$(pwd)":/app/data react-app
```

But when i run this 2nd command I am not able to browse the application. The container is suddenly in the exited(1) state.

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v "$(pwd)":/app react-app
```

in the log file I see this

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/app/.npm/_logs/2023-03-07T15_34_40_347Z-debug.log
sh: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! react-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/app/.npm/_logs/2023-03-07T15_37_46_136Z-debug.log
```

What i want to do is, map my local file with container's file system. I put all file in /app folder.

Here is the **dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir data
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . . 
ENV API_URL=http://api.myapp.com/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

even today I have run this command but the issue is still the same logs are the same and state exited(1) still the same

```
    Docker run -d -p 3000:5000 --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/app react-app

here is the Mounts output

"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/hamid/Docker/Mosh_Docker/docker_files/Section 5- Containers/section5-react-app",
                "Destination": "/app",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

it means that it has well mounted but docker is still in exited(1) state

Comment: In the second command, you overwrite the app directory with the mounted volume

Comment: The volume mount hides everything the Dockerfile `npm install`s; you're not really using the image at all.  Can you run `npm start` directly on your host without involving Docker?

Comment: @Paolo what do you want me to do? the purpose is to overwrite it because what i want is, whatever modification i do on the host should be reflected on the container. So like this i don't need to build my image again and again. Especially for the dev env

Comment: @bizimunda why don't you just build the image and run a docker container each time? your current approach doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Paolo in the dev env, lets say that you have to edit something, each time you edit something you have to rebuild the image. The purpose of mounting is to avoid rebuilding the image every time. It is time consuming and not the best practice for the dev env

Comment: @bizimunda why do you need docker then? just do it locally